# Move the asset directory for a dart project for a Jekyll blog post

Tags: dart, jekyll, angular-dart

I have a simple Angular-Dart web-page that works great offline with pub-serve. I want to add that page as a blog-post on Jekyll.

The problem is that Dart wants the assets (the package folder) in the same directory as the HTML file that call it. Jekyll produces that HTML file in a separate directory so that's not possible.

Basically I have:

```
_post/blabla.html <----- the html file/blog entry which will be built in another directory still
assets/main.js <----- the js-transformed script
assets/packages/.... <----- all the libs
```

But whenever I open `blabla.html` the jsfied Dart doesn't try to find the `packages` folder in the assets folder but in the _post folder. How do I tell it to look in a different directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

Angular can be redirected by using the following html code:

```
<base href="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/">
```

It's documented in angularjs but not angular dart which made it so hard to find!

I add that as an _include in the jekyll post and everything is peachy

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution 1

Try to add your page as a page at the root of your site, instead of using it a a post.

The `blabla.html` will then be at `yourdomain.tld/blabla.html` an then refer to `assets/script.js` as `yourdomain.tld/assets/script.js`.

#### Solution 2

Use the [`baseurl` variable](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/#project-page-url-structure) in `_config.yml`.

The point to your assets with `<script src="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/main.js"></script>`. This will target aseets relative to the root of your site.

Comment: hey thanks, but let me explain better. My problem is not to link the .js file from my html one. As you say, solution 2 takes care of that. My problem is that once main.js is called, it looks for packages ( and .html angular templates) not where main.js is but where the original .html that called it is! That is what I am trying to fix

Comment: Maybe a configuration variable in your main.js instruct you code to look for packages in a certain place. Look for it.

Comment: found the right angular directive! It was hidden deep in the angularjs documentation and not mentioned even once in angular dart but oh well